# Querying court data by citation on DBpedia using SPARQL?

Tags: sparql, dbpedia

I'm new to DBpedia.

What I'd like to be able to do is look up a case given it's legal citation. A legal citation usually involves a "volume", "reporter", and "page number". For example, for the case Loving v. Virginia, the DBPedia resource http://dbpedia.org/page/Loving_v._Virginia shows that the case has volume dbpprop:usvol = 388, page dbpprop:uspage = 1 (and the reporter is "US", which I suppose is baked into the usvol and uspage).

So, what's the SPARQL query that I could use to retrieve all the information contained in the Loving v. Virginia page given that I know its volume and page number? I know that it's volume is 388, its page is 1, and it's in the US reporter -- so how do I turn that into a SPARQL query?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is actually a pretty good use case for SPARQL's [`DESCRIBE`](http://www.w3.org/TR/sparql11-query/#describe) query type.  Using the `uspage` and `usvol` as you've described, you can simply get the `?case` with the specified page and volume, and `DESCRIBE` it:

```
DESCRIBE ?case WHERE { 
  ?case dbpprop:uspage 1 ;
        dbpprop:usvol 388 .
}
```

[SPARQL results](http://dbpedia.org/sparql?default-graph-uri=http%3A%2F%2Fdbpedia.org&query=DESCRIBE+%3Fcase+WHERE+%7B+%0D%0A++%3Fcase+dbpprop%3Auspage+1+%3B%0D%0A++++++++dbpprop%3Ausvol+388+.%0D%0A%7D&format=text%2Frdf%2Bn3&timeout=30000&debug=on)

If, for some reason, you want to use a [`SELECT`](http://www.w3.org/TR/sparql11-query/#select) query, you could do that too:

```
SELECT ?subject ?predicate ?object WHERE { 
  { ?case dbpprop:uspage 1 ;
          dbpprop:usvol 388 .
    BIND( ?case as ?subject ) 
    ?subject ?predicate ?object 
  }
  UNION 
  { ?case dbpprop:uspage 1 ;
          dbpprop:usvol 388 .
    BIND( ?case as ?object ) 
    ?subject ?predicate ?object 
  }
}
```

[SPARQL results](http://dbpedia.org/sparql?default-graph-uri=http%3A%2F%2Fdbpedia.org&query=SELECT+%3Fsubject+%3Fpredicate+%3Fobject+WHERE+%7B+%0D%0A++%7B+%3Fcase+dbpprop%3Auspage+1+%3B%0D%0A++++++++++dbpprop%3Ausvol+388+.%0D%0A++++BIND%28+%3Fcase+as+%3Fsubject+%29+%0D%0A++++%3Fsubject+%3Fpredicate+%3Fobject+%0D%0A++%7D%0D%0A++UNION+%0D%0A++%7B+%3Fcase+dbpprop%3Auspage+1+%3B%0D%0A++++++++++dbpprop%3Ausvol+388+.%0D%0A++++BIND%28+%3Fcase+as+%3Fobject+%29+%0D%0A++++%3Fsubject+%3Fpredicate+%3Fobject+%0D%0A++%7D%0D%0A%7D&format=text%2Fhtml&timeout=30000&debug=on)